# photoshop merging shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I draw one shape in Photoshop. Later I draw another on it and wanna merge them both. No way I can do it. Please help. :(

My combine shape option is active. Still I cant make it happen :@

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly why you should use Illustrator for this type of work, 100%, 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing is an illustration made of raster layers (layers made of pixels). These aren't shape layers.

To create an actual Shape layer (a vector shape), you need to select the "Shape" option in the Pen Tool options before drawing your shape. Then you can add a stroke or fill to it.

[image]

Shape layers have a special Vector icon to show that they are different from ordinary raster layers.

[image]

Once you have made several Shape layers, you can select them in the layers panel, right click and choose *Merge Shapes*.

The options you are showing for Combine, Subtract, Intersect, etc, only work with vectors, specifically if you want to draw two or more vectors on the same layer. These options will not merge Shapes on different layers, and they can't be used with raster layers at all.

Note that if you have two or more vectors on the same layer, or if you try to merge shapes, they can only have one fill or stroke colour. It's probably better not to merge shape layers unless you really need to.

If you have raster layers, it is also possible to merge these. The process is similar. Select the layers in the layers panel, right click them and choose *Merge Layers*.  However, once again this probably not a good idea as this is destructive. Only merge layers if you really must.

One more thing, Photoshop is not the best software for this kind of work.  If you want to create vector images, it's much better to use Adobe Illustrator. Photoshop has extremely limited vector capabilities which might be OK for something quite simple.